# Is it possible to retrieve page margin definitions from an attached template in Word 2013 using Word VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-template

I've built an addin template (dotm) for Word 2013 that contains various macros to automate repetitive and laborious tasks on the Active document. They are run from controls on a userform. All work fine but there is one thing I can't seem to do.

The scenario is I receive a document not based on a specific template (different page setup, for example), one macro attach's a template (dotx) to the active document. What I'd like to able to do is to use a macro to get the page margin values from the attached template and apply them to the active document.
I can't figure out how to get this to work, or if it is possible.

Any advice would be greatly welcomed.
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try tinkering with the [PageSetup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/pagesetup-object-word), which has a `TopMargin`, `BottomMargin`, `LeftMargin` and `RightMargin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ...

```
Sub TemplateMargin()
Dim doc As Word.Document, tDoc As Word.Document
Set doc = ActiveDocument
Set tDoc = ActiveDocument.attachedTemplate.OpenAsDocument
With doc.PageSetup
    .TopMargin = tDoc.PageSetup.TopMargin
    .BottomMargin = tDoc.PageSetup.BottomMargin
    .LeftMargin = tDoc.PageSetup.LeftMargin
    .RightMargin = tDoc.PageSetup.RightMargin
End With
tDoc.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.